# jsreport render to writableStream

Tags: node.js, pdf, express, jsreport

I'm trying to let jsreport write to a writablestream, if I print the buffer in the writablestream I get a pdf desciption, but if I save to a pdf file I get a error that the pdf file is corrupted.

```
function streamtoPdf(template, callback) {
    var ws = new stream;
    ws.writable = true;
    ws.bytes = 0;
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

    ws.write = function (buf) {
        ws.bytes += buf.length;
        console.log(buf);
        ws.pdf += decoder.write(buf);
    }

    ws.end = function (buf) {
        if (arguments.length) ws.write(buf);
        ws.writable = false;
        // console.log(ws.pdf)
        callback(ws.pdf);
    }
    renderPDF(template, ws);
}

//create a pdf from a template.
function renderPDF(template, writableStream) {
    jsreport.render("<h1>Hello world</h1>").then(function (out) {

        out.result.pipe(writableStream);

    }).catch(function (e) {
        res.end(e.message);
    });
}
```

If I use jsreport with `out.result.pipe(res)` I get a pdf with **hello world**, but with my method I get an error. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
 var jsreport = require('jsreport'),
     fs = require('fs'),
     Stream = require('stream');

 function streamtoPdf(template, callback) {
     var ws = new Stream.Writable;
     var bufs = []

     ws.write = function(buf) {
         bufs.push(buf);
     }

     ws.end = function(buf) {
         if (arguments.length) {
             bufs.push(buf)
         }
         ws.pdf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
         ws.writable = false;
         callback(ws.pdf);
     }
     renderPDF(template, ws);
 }

 //create a pdf from a template.
 function renderPDF(template, writableStream) {
     jsreport.render("<h1>Hello world</h1>").then(function(out) {
         out.result.pipe(writableStream);

     }).catch(function(e) {
         res.end(e.message);
     });
 }
 streamtoPdf('', function(wStream) {
     //console.log(wStream)
     fs.writeFile('myPdf', wStream, function(err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log('It\'s saved!');
     });
 });
```

The first problem was that "ws.pdf" was initially undefined so that caused an unexpected "undefined" word in pdf and causing corruption!
Anyway the real problem is that you got a buffer in callback and you encoded to utf8 so even the pdf was created it was blank!